# Player downloads all moof part of a fragment mp4 file before playing

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, fmp4

I converted a mp4 to fragment mp4 with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i ./input.mp4 -y -b:a 32k -vcodec libx265 -b:v 320k -bufsize 320k -tag:v hvc1 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 -movflags faststart+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+dash+global_sidx -chunk_duration 500000000 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 ./output.mp4
```

But when playing, the player send many http requests to download all the moof part:

[image]

[image]

But I think in normal case the player only need to download the head part of the video file to play.

So is there anything wrong with my ffmpeg parameters? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production.

Comment: PS: @happyz90 What happens if you remove that `global_sidx` part? Investigate what it does and see if you need it in your command (it could be causing the issue, or maybe not)...

Comment: The progress bar doesn't work if `global_sidx` removed. @VC.One

Comment: @happyz90 Okay so it must be something else. Double-check your other FFmpeg settings/options like what is your actual expected "duration per chunk" (???) and consider if your shown microseconds value is correct for getting that result... Is the input playing ok (no bad timestamps)? What is total duration? Also not obvious what is your "player" in your _"player downloads all chunks"_  but the important part is testing other players. How can my custom player (or anyones) code test your first two chunks? Fastest way to get an answer is to share testable things to recreate the same issue you get.